# Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated return always false in safari

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, safari, openid, dotnetopenauth

I am using DotNetOpenId and Asp.NET MVC. I have the following problem:

When using IE not problem I can login and when I check the Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated I get true. If I test this in Safari for Windows the Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false. If I use Safari in Mac I can Login without a problem.

Any Idea? What Other Info can I give you so you can Help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the release of Safari 4, all started to work.

Answer (score 1):

You *are* logging into your web site using Safari, right?  I can't tell from your question whether you expect to be able to log in using IE and then switch to Safari and still be logged in. But that's certainly not possible.

Can you tell me more about what happens when you're using Safari?  Does the login appear to finish but then it still behaves like you're not logged in.

Comment: No I want to log with Safari or IE or Chrome or FireFox. If I use IE, Chrome or FireFox is Ok, Safari I get the error.

Comment: If no error message is being displayed then I'm afraid I can't help you aside from suggesting you sniff for cookies in transit between Safari and your server, or go into Safari's cookie manager if it has one and see if the cookies are being persisted.  Perhaps it has a privacy setting that is prevent session cookies from being created?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this a while back. It turned out that the cookie I was setting capitalized the first letter of the domain when set and the javascript we were using was looking for all lower case. This worked fine on every browser but one... Safari for Windows treated Example.com and example.com as two different domains and saw the cookie request as a cross-domain and blocked it.